# How to open System specific default apps in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to transfer data from my app like name,phno,email id from my app to default contact app.

Comment: class Contact {
  Contact({
    this.givenName,
    this.middleName,
    this.prefix,
    this.suffix,
    this.familyName,
    this.company,
    this.jobTitle,
    this.emails,
    this.phones,
    this.postalAddresses,
    this.avatar,
  });                                                                                                                                         In contact_service.dart how can i initialize members of Contact by declaring a data member of Contact contact;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[contacts_service](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service) plugin will do that for you with both iOS and Android

Example code:

```dart
final contact = Contact({
    givenName = "first name",
    middleName = "middle name",
    prefix = "mr",
    familyName = "last name",
    this.emails = <Item>[Item(label: "Home", value: "home@example.com")],
    this.phones = <Item>[Item(label: "Home", value: "1234567980")],
  });

await ContactsService.addContact(contact)
```

Comment: how to set a contact data

Comment: _call() async {
    Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.addContact(contact)
  }                                                                                                                                                                      i am using this method to add contact but how can i set a contact variable from the strings that i got from my app..

Comment: I couldn't initialize phone number and email id as it was of type string how can i convert it to type Iterable<Item> datatype

Comment: Vote up please. Desperate for rep!!

Comment: But now after using contact_service: 0.2.4 while debugging  it's showing an error "D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver" The only solution is to migrate to androidX i guess

Comment: i have no idea what is wrong there. googling the error might help

Comment: o.k i will look for it